# Better default values for a given type

Tags: f#

Say I have DUs

```
type Zero = Zero
type Succ<'a> = Succ of 'a
```

I can use `Unchecked.defaultof<Zero Succ Succ>` when I'm passing the value to an inline function that only uses the type of that value. But how would I go about getting a proper value of a given type? One that isn't null.

Since the only valid value that has a type `Zero Succ Succ` is `Succ(Succ(Zero))` I feel like I should be able to get it.

I don't care for intermediate type safety so I'm ok with typecasts.

I've tried this:

```
let rec makeProperSucc (a : Succ<'a>) = Succ(makeProperNum Unchecked.defaultof<'a>)

and makeProperNum (obj : obj) : obj = 
    if obj :? Zero then Zero :> obj
    else makeProperSucc (obj :?> Succ<obj>) :> obj

let instance<'a>() = makeProperNum Unchecked.defaultof<'a> :?> 'a
```

Which doesn't work because `defaultof` gives me a null and all the type information is lost because I send it to a function expecting obj.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about defining a static member with static constraints in the DU?

Here's a quick draft with a unary operator:

```
type Zero = Zero with
    static member (!!) Zero = Zero

type Succ<'a> = Succ of 'a with
    static member inline (!!) (Succ a) = Succ (!!a)

// Test
!!(Unchecked.defaultof<Succ<Succ<Succ<Zero>>>>)
// val it : Succ<Succ<Succ<Zero>>> = Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))
```

I used an operator to keep it simple, but you can also write the static constraints by hand or use the [inline helper](https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl/blob/master/FsControl.Core/InlineHelper.fs) as you did before in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723416/type-level-number-arithmetic).

**UPDATE**

If you want to use the [inline helper](https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl/blob/0c72e9f9e9303c02712a867555a689b77b713057/FsControl.Core/InlineHelper.fs) module, used in [FsControl](https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl) 1.x, you can do it this way:

```
type Instance = Instance with
    static member        instance(Instance, _:unit    ) = fun () -> ()
    static member        instance(Instance, _:Zero    ) = fun () -> Zero
    static member inline instance(Instance, _:Succ<'b>) = fun () -> 
        Succ (Inline.instance Instance ())

let inline instance() = Inline.instance Instance ()

let test:Succ<Succ<Zero>> = instance()
```

If you want to use the notation `instance<'t>()`  you will have to disable the warning.

Comment: Well I've tried with the inline helper but couldn't get it to resolve. I'm kind of unclear on what exactly makes it possible or impossible to infer the type. Thank you for the answer, as usual.

Comment: Great! Well, here's my attempt if you maybe want to see where I messed up http://pastebin.com/QqCTcg5Z Why does explicitly passing the remaining type make it unable to solve it?

Comment: Your code works as well for me. The only difference with my code is that you don't need to pass an argument representing the instance which you generate with default of, that's already solved in the inline helper.

Comment: Could we obviate the need for [FsControl](https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl) in this case, by combining the static member constraint invocation with the type initialization of the second argument in a single let-bound function? E.g. `module Inline = let inline instance (a:^a) (x:^x) = ((^a or ^r):(static member instance:^a* ^r->_) (a, Unchecked.defaultof< ^r>)) x : ^r`

Comment: Of course you don't need FsControl, I thought it was clear that you can always write the constraints by hand.